# how do i query magento for delivery address by order number?

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to report order numbers and matching delivery addresses from Magento 1 orders data.

I have no idea where, or how to query for this report.

I have found answers to this question such as : 
"enter:

```
$order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet(1);
$order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet(2);"
```

But I have no idea WHERE to enter that code!?!? or how to execute it....

Might be a silly question - but we all have to start somewhere ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the increment ID for the order (the one that shows when viewing an order, right at the top), you can load it as follows, where $orderId is set to whatever that ID is:

```
$orderId = "E00047487";
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
```

Now to get the billing address information, just use the code that you've provided in your question, or alternatively something like this:

```
$billingStreet  = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('street');
$billingStreet1 = $billingStreet[0];
$billingStreet2 = $billingStreet[1];
$billingStreet3 = $billingStreet[2];
```

This pulls all of the billing street information into an array, and each part of it can be accessed like above (how you'd access an array typically)